# Can't delete file - open i Rstudio

Tags: r, delete-file, unlink

Is there a way to force R to delete a file using

```
unlink()
```

when its open in R?

When trying to R throws the warning: Warning message:
In file.remove(ls) :
  cannot remove file 'dat.csv', reason 'Permission denied'. I have a large Global Environment, and have difficulties finding the reason that the file is in use.

When i try to delete in using windows, i get the error: the action cannot be completed because the file is open in Rstudio r session.

Alternativly, is there a way to see which entity is blocking the delete?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1888/

Answer (score -1):

Just use command dev.off() in R.
And you will shut down all the underlying running device until the null device.
Then it should be ok to open pdf files.